# How MySQL does the fulltext search if I need to find two words that are not close each other

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

If I am using MySQL [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) to find term " **ford fiesta** ", and I am searching from the field that looks like this: "**cars ford engines fiesta**".

Is MySQL going to give me a result ? I do not want it to only find " **ford fiesta** " if these words are next to each other in the field that I am searching from, for example " **cars ford fiesta engines** ".

If MySQL is not going to give me a result by default, can I configure it to do so ( to match words if they are appearing anywhere in the text that I am searching from ), or is there any other way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Try this and see what you get. By name `full text serach` should return all data matching with the word and does not matter how and where they appear, how ever you can tell mysql to see if both the words are preset in a row. Check the manual for more details

Answer (score 2):

Use `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where `field` REGEXP 'ford.*fiesta' = 1
```

It will return those records whose `field` field contains string that has words `ford` and `fiesta` with any string between them. `REGEXP` returns 1 on match and 0 if not matched.

Comment: But with that query I am not using fulltext search ? This is just regexp search ?

Comment: So if I want to search for "ford fiesta" in "asd ford sds fefer vbh fiesta". This query would find it ? Anyway I gues that the way REGEXP condition is build must be dynamic, I mean sometime user may enter only 1 word to search, somethimes 2, sometimes 5...

Comment: yes, you can test it. Sure you can use PHP variable to provide for this regexp pattern.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try this if real http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html do not work as I want. I hope that regarding performances regexp is not slower.

Answer (score 0):

Use like and then add wildcard parameters.

as such

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%ford fiesta%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe completely unrelated, but when I started to create a bit more complex search engines I started using a special Database for it.

Take a look at elasticSearch, once you get it up and running it is crazy simple to specify needs like yours.

Specially the query_string from ElasticSearch would fit your needs. You can even specify what fields you want to run the query on.

As I said, once you want to get over from a simple search to advanced search, MYSQL ain't the right one to do the job.

Cheers

Comment: I heard about ElasticSearch, but do not know anything about it. I can not find good tutorial for beginner that will explain by examples what you have to do to use ElasticSearch in php. :(